# Store <td> element into database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dynamically created table. Means the header is fixed and the row data will append dynamically after certain ajax call. My question is how to save quantity value with product_id (which is the `<tr>` id) in database?

```
 <tr> 
   <th></th>                   
   <th>Product Name</th>
   <th>Unit Price</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>                   
   <th>Total </th>
 </tr>
```

// This part will append after ajax call i have used autocomplete search

```
 <tr id="+ui.item.id+">   // product_id
    <td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td>
     <td>"+ui.item.value+"</td>
     <td>"+ui.item.unit_price+"</td>
     <td><input type='text' class='quantity' value='1'></td> //quantity
     <td class='total'>"+ui.item.unit_price+"</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: you have three answers to your question. Accept the one that works for you or leave a comment. The people that wrote the answer for you did that for more reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the quantity and product in array:

```
     <td><input type='text' name="id[]" class='productclass' value='+ui.item.id+'></td>
     <td><input type='text' name="quantity[]" class='quantity' value='1'></td>
```

if you don't want to show the product id, you can hide:

```
<input type='hidden' name="id[]" class='productclass' value="+ui.item.id+">
```

On the server side:

```
//Check input data
if(in_array("",$_POST['id'], true)){
//Empty id
}else{
  $countid = count($_POST['id']);
  for($j=0;$j<$countid;$j++){
      $id = $_POST['id'][$j];
      $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$j];
      //code for saving into the database
  }
}
```

Comment: i can't keep id as input type text.

Comment: See the updated code, you can put somewhere between the tr element

Comment: if i keep different name for input type. How do i track which product has the quantity?

Comment: The for loop will give you each item with its quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Try do to this. For this particularly select with reference id wise.

Comment: Try do to this. For this particularly select with reference id wise                               
<td><input id="ID" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="quantity" type="text"></td>

Answer (score 0):

> How About this (Just replace your **ui.item** with fixed value)

```
<table>
     <tr class="product-list" id="100">
        <td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td>
         <td>Product 1</td>
         <td>200</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
         <td class='total'>200</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="product-list" id="101">
        <td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td>
         <td>Product 2</td>
         <td>250</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
         <td class='total'>250</td>
      </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="postData()">Post</button>
```

> Using jQuery

```
function postData(){
    var products = [];
    $('.product-list').each(function(index, el){

      var productId = $(this).attr('id');
      var quantity = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
      var total = $(this).find('.total').text();
      products[index]['id'] = productId;
      products[index]['quantity'] = quantity;
      products[index]['total'] = total;
    });

  //now post $products through AJAX


}
```